# Not the right Activity java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, securityexception

I read all other answers about this problem but it doesn't help me.

I have an app (MyApp) which include a library (named lib (example)). In my app, I call LoginActivity in my lib. 
But I have this exception.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=fr.myotherapp/.activity.LoginActivity
```

Myotherapp is a other app which I created and installed in the same device.

I don't set `"exported"="true"` in myotherapp manifest because I dont want to use this one but I set  `"exported"="true"` for the activity in the lib manifest.
I use Android Studio.
Why does Android want to use this one even if I call the activity like this ?

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, fr.lib.activity.LoginActivity.class);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, try adding `manifestmerger.enabled=true` to your project.properties file.

relevant docs :

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Android-Manifest-file-merging

https://roostertech.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/manifest-merger/

Comment: Nope, I use Android Studio.